# Conditional not working as expected in github actions

Tags: github, conditional-statements, action

I have a step in my github action that's on a cron job that will alert me on MS teams when there's drift in our infrastructure. The terraform step works perfectly and I can see the output via my debug step which is in steps.plan.outputs.PLAN_OUTPUT.

However, the condition is never met. I've tried all sorts of different syntax and it just doesn't seem to work. The only thing I can think is that contains() doesn't work for multi-line input strings, but I can't find anything to confirm that.

I have confirmed that the notification works, so it can't be that - it has to be the condition not firing.

```
      - name: Terraform Plan
        id: plan
        run: |
          EOF=$(dd if=/dev/urandom bs=15 count=1 status=none | base64)
          echo "PLAN_OUTPUT<<$EOF" >> "$GITHUB_ENV"
          terraform plan -lock=false -no-color -var-file=${{ env.VAR_FILE }} -out=tfplan >> "$GITHUB_ENV"
          echo "$EOF" >> "$GITHUB_ENV"

      - name: Output the plan (debug)
        run: |
          echo "${{ steps.plan.outputs.PLAN_OUTPUT }}"

      - name: Notify teams if there's plan drift
        if: contains(steps.plan.outputs.PLAN_OUTPUT, 'to destroy') && !contains(steps.plan.outputs.PLAN_OUTPUT, '0 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy')
        uses: skitionek/notify-microsoft-teams@master
        with:
          webhook_url: ${{ secrets.MSTEAMS_WEBHOOK }}
          raw: >-
            {
              "@type": "MessageCard",
              "@context": "http://schema.org/extensions",
              "title": "*Terraform drift detected*",
              "text": "Details here: <https://github.com/${{github.repository}}/actions/runs/${{github.run_id}}|View>"
            }
        env:
          MSTEAMS_WEBHOOK: ${{ secrets.MSTEAMS_TEST_WEBHOOK }}
```

And here's a snippet of the string steps.plan.outputs.PLAN_OUTPUT from the debug step:

```
  Terraform will perform the following actions:
  
    # azurerm_mariadb_server.mariadb-regional[0] will be updated in-place
    ~ resource "azurerm_mariadb_server" "mariadb-regional" {
          id                            = "/subscriptions/***/resourceGroups/rg-apac-database-regional/providers/Microsoft.DBforMariaDB/servers/mariadb-regional-apac-prod"
          name                          = (sensitive value)
        ~ tags                          = {
            - "drift-test-tag-to-delete" = "john" -> null
              # (3 unchanged elements hidden)
          }
          # (14 unchanged attributes hidden)
      }
  
  Plan: 0 to add, 1 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

Result:
[image: Step doesn't fire]